# Log in failed on database for local administrative users

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, windows-services

One of my service in windows server reads from an xml file username and passwords build the query and connects to the database. The service was working fine until the IT turned off the local administrative users.I am keep getting message

> Database logon failed.

When the local administrative user is turned on the service works fine. Does any body know how to fix this issue.

```
private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
          GetServerInfo()


                ConnectionInfo ci = new ConnectionInfo();
                ci.ConnStringOuter = "Data Source=" +  ServerName + ";Initial Catalog=" +  Database + ";Persist Security Info=True;User ID=" +  AdminUser + ";Password=" +  AdminPass + ";Application Name= Reports.Net Service;Connect Timeout=90";

                SqlConnection cnAccounts = new SqlConnection(ci.ConnStringOuter);
                string qryAccounts = "SELECT a.id, a.LastRunStatus, a.TimeOffSet FROM events a WITH (NOLOCK) JOIN Data d ON a.DbID = d.DbID WHERE a.isOn = 1 AND (a.EventDesc LIKE '%AR%') AND mygroup='Notification' AND d.AppName='RoomNet' ";
                cnAccounts.Open();
                SqlCommand cmdAccounts = new SqlCommand(qryAccounts, cnAccounts);
                SqlDataReader rdrAccounts = cmdAccounts.ExecuteReader();
  }



private void GetServerInfo()
        {
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            try
            {

                string AppPath = Directory.GetParent(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location).FullName;
                StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(StrAppPath + "\\XMLServer.xml");
                xDoc.Load(rdr);
                rdr.Close();
                rdr.Dispose();

                XmlNodeList xRequest = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("XMLServer");
                foreach (XmlNode node in xRequest)
                {
                    ServerName = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("ServerName")[0].InnerText;
                    AdminUser = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("AdminUser")[0].InnerText;
                    AdminPass = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("AdminPass")[0].InnerText;
                   Database = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Database")[0].InnerText;
                    OutgoingPort = Convert.ToInt32(xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("EmailPort")[0].InnerText);
                    SMTPFromAddress = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("SMTPFromAddress")[0].InnerText;
                    SMTPUserID = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("SMTPUserID")[0].InnerText;
                    SMTPPassword = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("SMTPPassword")[0].InnerText;
                    SMTPServer = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("SMTPServer")[0].InnerText;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                ConnectionInfo ci = new ConnectionInfo();
                WriteEventToWindowsLog("Log", " failed. Message: " + err.Message);

            }

            xDoc = null;
        }
```

The xml file has the iis-admin user name and password.

Comment: How do you fix it? Don't log on in your program as the local administrative user. You need to update your question showing how you are making your connection strings (reading from the xml and populating the username and password) for us to help you any further than that.

Comment: do you have a `DBA` have them set up a Service Account for that Sql User that only that Service will use.. simple as that

Comment: I think you are using windows credentials.  SQL Server can use either a windows credential or a SQL credential.  The database needs to be modified to use windows credentials.  Then make a windows group account for the database and add all users to the group account.

Comment: In the Xml file instead of server name if i add the IP address the service works  fine even with local administrative users disabled.

Comment: I am using sql authentication to connect to the server.Not windows authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the server solved all the issues.Thank you every one for all your answers.I learned lots of things from everyone's answer.